# How can i verify if i'm adding atributes to a list that are equal?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

```
import entidades.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Profissional prof = new Profissional(null, null);
        List<Profissional> profissional = new ArrayList<Profissional>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean loop = true;
        while(loop == true) {
            String comando = sc.next().toUpperCase();

            if (comando.contentEquals("RP")) {
                String nomePro = sc.nextLine();
                String categoriaPro = sc.nextLine();
                prof.NomeVerificacao(profissional, nomePro, categoriaPro);
            }
            if(comando.contentEquals("SAIR")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        for(Profissional pro : profissional) {
            System.out.println(pro);
```

This is my Main, it's running fine but i don´t think it is adding the atributes to the list and not verifying either.

i want to add the atributes to a list so i can create different objets but they can not have at least the name equal.

```
public class Profissional {
    private String nome;
    private String categoria;

    public Profissional(String nome, String categoria) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }


        public void NomeVerificacao(List<Profissional> profissional ,String nome, String categoria) {
        if(profissional.isEmpty() == true) {
            profissional.add(new Profissional(nome, categoria));
        }else {
            for(Profissional pro : profissional) {
                if(pro.nome.contentEquals(nome)) {
                    System.out.println("Já Exite esse nome");

                }else {
                    profissional.add(new Profissional(nome, categoria));    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "nome=" + nome + ", categoria=" + categoria;
    }


}
```

this is the Profissional Class.

I'm almost there i think but the output keeps saying that the name exists even though it is the first name i'm inserting.

Comment: Your problem being?

Comment: Let me clarify some details. You have a console input and if keyword "RP" in typed it indicates that further input will have : "name category" format until the keyword "SAIR" is entered, right? So you'd like to read the entire file into a list without name duplication. Am I right?

Comment: It's more like a command that means "Register Professional".

Comment: and i'm trying to see if i have professionals in this "Hospital" that have the name.

Comment: it's basically what you said but i don't understand the "Files" part

Comment: I have changed it to console. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes it's correct!

Comment: i just want to print a message that already exists that name so i won't add to the list

Comment: If you weren't sure if items were added to the list, why didn't you print values to the console for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code on my machine and made 3 changes into it, and it's working for me now,

1)

String nomePro = sc.next();
   String categoriaPro = sc.next();

2) In professional class just changed this function a bit:

```
public void NomeVerificacao(List<Profissional> profissional, String nome, String categoria) {
    if (profissional.isEmpty() == true) {
        profissional.add(new Profissional(nome, categoria));
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < profissional.size(); i++) {
            if (profissional.get(i).nome.equals(nome)) {
                System.out.println("Já Exite esse nome");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == profissional.size()) {
            profissional.add(new Profissional(nome, categoria));
        }
    }
}
```

3) At the end of the class Main, wrote sc.close(); to close the scanner.

```
i/p and o/p : 
1) RP
   red
   color
2) RP
   orange
   color
3) RP
   orange
   paint
   Já Exite esse nome

4) SAIR
   nome=red, categoria=color
   nome=orange, categoria=color
```

As you can see in above i/p and o/p, nome=red and nome=orange with categoria=color are added in the list but when we tried to add the same nome=orange again but with different category as paint it didn't add it and printed the message "Já Exite esse nome".
and after entering SAIR, the toString(); printed the list content at the end. So the message will be printed only if we try to add the object with the same name again int list (not the first or any other times).

Further optimizations are possible but for now, it will work!

Comment: you only changed the Professional class??

Comment: How do i give more reputation?? because i was around this long time

Comment: Filipe Mota thanks for your acknowledgement. I don't know abt reputation m new here :P

Comment: Ya the major change was in your professional class. I am happy that it worked for u!

Comment: Just other thing! i edited the "NomeVerificacao" function and your code works perfectly but i want to understand why mine doen't work :( can you see the error?

Comment: yes, the thing is List is a collection and whenever we iterate collection and at the same time(in the loop) add or remove some element into/from it, it gives us an exception.

Comment: and the message "Já Exite esse nome" was printed for the first element also coz, after adding the element in first if block the control was going inside for loop and inside that you used an if() condition to check if the passed nome and list->object's->nome are equal and in this case, since you added the same element in the list they are the same.

Comment: So i can't add in the same loop that i'm trying to do that check??

Comment: ya, you can't add or remove elements to/from the list, in the same loop in which you are iterating that list. That's why I added that new element outside that for loop.

Comment: And can you explain me what is it doing??

Comment: Because i'm trying to do my way following my logic but i don't know how to add the atribute outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static class Profissional {
        private String nome;
        private String categoria;

        public Profissional(String nome, String categoria) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.categoria = categoria;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {            
            List<Profissional> profissionalList= new ArrayList<>();

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true) {

                System.out.print("\r\nEnter comando:");
                String comando = sc.next().toUpperCase();

                if (comando.contentEquals("RP")) {                
                    System.out.print("nome: ");              
                    String nome = sc.next();
                    sc.nextLine(); // wait enter

                    System.out.print("categoria: ");              
                    String categoria = sc.next();
                    sc.nextLine(); // wait enter

                    // access constructor of Profissional
                    Constructor profCtor =  Profissional.class.getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
                    profCtor.setAccessible(true);                        
                    // create instance of Profissional
                    Profissional newItem = (Profissional) profCtor.newInstance(nome, categoria);

                    // avoid duplicate nome in profissionalList
                    boolean isExist = false;
                    for(Profissional pro : profissionalList) {
                       if(pro != null){
                           if(pro.nome.toLowerCase().equals(newItem.nome.toLowerCase())){
                               isExist = true;
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                    }
                    if(!isExist){
                        profissionalList.add(newItem );
                    }
                }
                if(comando.contentEquals("SAIR")) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(Profissional pro : profissionalList) {
                if(pro != null) {
                    System.out.println("nome: " + pro.nome + " categoria: " + pro.categoria);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());             
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if there is no input then "if (comando.contentEquals ("RP")) {" will not be executed.

Comment: ok thanks! and what does this "item" mean? "profissionalList.add(item);"?

Comment: It is like "(new Profissional(nomePro, categoriaPro)"?

Comment: item = newItem. Sorry I miss typo

Comment: new Profissional(nomePro, categoriaPro) = create instance (object) of Profissional class.

Comment: And that's what i'm trying to do it's to create instances in the list!

Comment: btw i have tried the code and it does't work, don't know what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I can propose the following solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Set is a data structure that makes sure you don't have a duplicated elements
    // in this case we use TreeSet structure that accepts comparator which tells that
    // we need to compare elements only by professional's name
    Set<Profissional> profissionals = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Profissional::getNome));

    while (true) {
        String comando = sc.next().toUpperCase();

        if (comando.contentEquals("RP")) {
            String nomePro = sc.next();
            String categoriaPro = sc.next();
            
            // add function returns true in case the element we're going to add
            // was not presented in Set structure yet. False otherwise.
            boolean isNew = profissionals.add(new Profissional(nomePro, categoriaPro));
            if (!isNew) {
                System.out.println("Professional with name " + nomePro + " already exists");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Professional with name " + nomePro + " was added");
            }
        } else if (comando.contentEquals("SAIR")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // just prints all professionals at the end of the program
    profissionals.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static class Profissional {

    private String nome;
    private String categoria;

    public Profissional(String nome, String categoria) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "nome=" + nome + ", categoria=" + categoria;
    }
}
```

The output will be the following:

> **RP**
>
> test test
>
> *Professional with name test was added*
>
> **RP**
>
> test1 test1
>
> *Professional with name test1 was added*
>
> **RP**
>
> test test3
>
> *Professional with name test already exists*
>
> **SAIR**
>
> *nome=test, categoria=test*
>
> *nome=test1, categoria=test1*

Comment: Don't know if i can do that way but i'll try to take the idea!

Comment: I will put some comments then :) Give me a minute

Comment: The thing is i can't use that "TreeSet" it has to be an array.

Comment: Don't know if it is basically the same but i don't think i can use that

Comment: this is not a problem at all, you can convert to list using the following `new ArrayList<>(profissionals);`

Comment: instead of threeSet i put that and it converts into a list??

Comment: What I mean is that once the code above is executed and you came to the line when you have to proceed working with your unique professionals and you're required your professionals to be a list then you can use `List<Profissional> list = new ArrayList<>(profissionals);` piece of code to get this conversion.